# VSCode JSDoc of Promise

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve('string');
});
```

The type of "promise" variable is `Promise<any>`, while it should be `Promise<string>`. Can I get it to automatically recognize what is being put in resolve()? I could manually describe type in docblock, but there's a pretty complicated object being put in resolve() and I would just like that it uses automatically generated doc.

Comment: If you just want a promise of a value there's a static method on the Promise constructor for that purpose: `const foo = Promise.resolve("some string");`. Using it may or may not make static analysis easier.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to automatically find out what you put into resolve if you don't have a helper around that promise.

You can create your "own types" and pass them to Promise like this :D

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{name: "John", lastName: "Doe", age: "infinite"}} MyComplicatedObject
 * @type {Promise<MyComplicatedObject>}
 */
const promise = new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve({ name: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 'infinite' });
});
```

You don't need to re-type them and you can also `import` them in the jsdoc annotation from other files, just like you would import any other file from js.

If you want to automatically detect what resolve is going to resolve you have a helper for that promise:

```js
/**
 * @template resT
 * @param {resT} whatToResolve
 * @returns {Promise<resT>}
 */
const myPromise = whatToResolve => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(whatToResolve);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My use case is actually, that I call some external method and want to resolve the promise with it.
`const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve(MyClass.method());
});`. How would I get VSCode to properly display that "promise" is of type `Promise<{...}>` and not `Promise<any>`. MyClass.method() has a proper JSdoc attached to it (it's auotmatically generated.